# Squid: how to redirect unknown host?

Tags: squid

On normal web surf,without proxy
when I type on the search bar "tiscali" "latest news"
Firefox or IE,redirect me to google.
Squid instead gives me "unknown host"
Is possible to tell squid to redirect to google search
when I type on the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty but working solution

```
    <HTML><HEAD>
</HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchURL = "%U";
var newSearchURL = searchURL.replace("http://","");
var newSearchURL = newSearchURL.replace("/","");
var redirectTo = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="
window.location = redirectTo + newSearchURL
</script>
```

Put it in (backup for security the old file)
/usr/share/squid/errors/YOURLOCALE/ERR_DNS_FAIL